# Bluetooth PAN connection - ARP not working

Tags: bluetooth, tcp, arp

My setup is an embedded device that is going to be accessed from a tablet (could be Android or iOS-based).

The device is accessed via Bluetooth and it implements the PAN profile (NAP role), such that the tablet sees it as a device through which it can access the internet.

I use DBus to register a NAP server with Bluez. This works fine, and Bluez creates a network interface named 'bnep0' when the tablet connects.
I have configured the bnep0 interface in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface bnep0 inet static
  address 10.254.239.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  post-up service isc-dhcp-server start
  pre-down service isc-dhcp-server stop
```

I use udev to bring the interface up/down using the a rule defined in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-bnep.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="bnep0" SUBSYSTEM=="net", RUN+="/sbin/ifup bnep0"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="bnep0", SUBSYSTEM=="net", RUN+="/sbin/ifdown bnep0"
```

As you can see, I use interface up/down events to start/stop a DHCP server that provides an IP address to the tablet.

My DHCP server is configured by the following lines in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.254.239.2 10.254.239.254;
}
```

As a side note, I also create a network bridge br0 in /etc/network/interfaces. That is required by Bluez in order to register a NAP interface:

```
iface br0 inet manual
  bridge_ports none
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_stp off
```

All this works fine. The tablet will perform Bluetooth pairing with my device and connect successfully. I can also observe that the tablet queries my device's DHCP server and gets assigned the address 10.254.239.2

On my device, I get the output from command 'ip addr show':

```
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 5c:e0:c5:af:7b:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::984d:cdff:fe4b:65be/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: bnep0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:e0:c5:af:7b:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.254.239.1/24 brd 10.254.239.255 scope global bnep0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5ee0:c5ff:feaf:7bf6/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I then launch an application on my embedded device, which opens a TCP server socket on address 10.254.239.1, port 15137. The application listens for incoming connections from the tablet.

Now I attempt to open a TCP client socket from the tablet to IP address 10.254.239.1. I can observe (using wireshark) that interface bnep0 receives ARP requests for IP address 10.254.239.1. But my device does not generate any ARP response, and the tablet application will time out when attempting to connect the TCP socket :-(

Likewise, if I try to ping the tablet from my embedded device, I observe that my device sends ARP requests for 10.254.239.2 to which the tablet responds normally. But it is as if the ARP response is not received by the device, because it does not send any ping request afterwards.

Thus, the symptom is that incoming ARP packets on interface bnep0 are not processed.

I really cannot understand what I am missing. Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, the problem was my own lack of understanding of how a network bridge works.

I found the very informative HOWTO [Persistently bridge traffic between two or more Ethernet interfaces (Debian)](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/persistently_bridge_traffic_between_two_or_more_ethernet_interfaces_on_debian.html), which clearly states that once a network interface has been added to a bridge, it cannot be used as an endpoint for IP traffic.

Thus, what I needed to do was to change the setup of my network interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces such that the bridge becomes the IP endpoint:

```
iface br0 inet static
  address 10.254.239.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  bridge_ports none
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_stp off
```

Note that the section for bnep0 can be completely omitted.

Also thanks to [ELinux - Bluetooth Network](http://elinux.org/Bluetooth_Network) for inspiration.